# Display empty point in bar graph

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to display statuses for somes IDs stored in a DB. Everything works, but I also need to show empty points. They should appear as a gap between the statuses that actually have IDs in them. The following query defines the data displayed:

```
SELECT [SnapshotTime]
  ,[Id]
  ,[Status]
FROM [Features]
WHERE (Status = '0_BB'
OR Status = '1_RT'  
OR Status = '2_AA' 
OR Status = '3_EC' 
OR Status = '4_FD' 
OR Status = '5_ID' 
OR Status = '6_DR' 
OR Status = '7_finished')
AND
([SnapshotTime] = (SELECT MAX([SnapshotTime]) FROM [Features]))
AND (FeatureSet = @System OR @System = 'ALL')
```

@System is a parameter accessible for the user. E.g. "ALL" will give all Systems. What I need now is a forced display for all statuses. If status "2_AA" contains no IDs, this query will lead to a bar graph simply excluding that status, but I want it to be shown nevertheless (no bar then, but a gap, indicating there is no ID in that status).

I attempted EmptyPoint Values, but there are simply no null values, so this doesn't help. A dataTable containing hard coded Strings for all status seems like a solution, but I have no idea how to insert and unite that into this query or report. So please help me with forced empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Tino brought me onto the right lane. The following code fits my needs:

```
DECLARE @Statuses table(
SnapshotTime varchar(255),
Id varchar(255),
Status varchar(255));

INSERT INTO @Statuses(SnapshotTime,Id,Status)
VALUES ('-1',NULL,'2_AA');
INSERT INTO @Statuses(SnapshotTime,Id,Status)
VALUES ('-1',NULL,'3_EC');
INSERT INTO @Statuses(SnapshotTime,Id,Status)
VALUES ('-1',NULL,'4_FD');
INSERT INTO @Statuses(SnapshotTime,Id,Status)
VALUES ('-1',NULL,'5_ID');
INSERT INTO @Statuses(SnapshotTime,Id,Status)
VALUES ('-1',NULL,'6_DR');

SELECT [SnapshotTime]
      ,[Id]
      ,[Status]
  FROM [Features]
  WHERE (Status = '0_BB'
  OR Status = '1_RT'  
  OR Status = '2_AA' 
  OR Status = '3_EC' 
  OR Status = '4_FD' 
  OR Status = '5_ID' 
  OR Status = '6_DR' 
  OR Status = '7_finished'
)
  AND
  ([SnapshotTime] = (SELECT MAX([SnapshotTime]) FROM [Features]))
  AND (FeatureSet = @System OR @System = 'ALL')
UNION ALL
  SELECT [SnapshotTime]
      ,[Id]
      ,[Status]
  FROM @Statuses
```

I'm pretty sure this won't work without [adding EmptyPoint properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207051.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could join with another table, containing all statuses, and use ISNULL for when there's no SnapshotTime:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(f.[SnapshotTime], 0), f.[Id], s.[Status]
FROM
    [Features] AS f
    RIGHT JOIN [Statuses] AS s
        ON
            f.[Status] = s.[Status]
WHERE
    ([SnapshotTime] = (SELECT MAX([SnapshotTime]) FROM [Features])) AND
    (FeatureSet = @System OR
        @System = 'ALL')
```

This will always show every status, and show 0 when no SnapshotTime is available.

Haven't tested the code though, just edited yours.

Comment: Could you tell me how to add a table with all the statuses? In the datasets? I'm stuck on that point.

Comment: Where is your Features table located? Just create a new table there, containing all statuses.

Comment: So theres no possibility to add a datatable to the report itself? OK, I'll see if I can create a table on the DB

Comment: You could insert all statuses in a [table variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx), or use a [common table expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Comment: that helped me! I have a working solution with declared table that contains all statuses. However, I think the solution needs EmptyPoint Values

Comment: Drop the ISNULL and you should have empty gaps where no data is available. More on empty points [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207051.aspx).

Comment: See my answer below. I already used emptypoints and it's working!